# Get value of children data-attribute (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select menu with a list of options. Each options has a data attribute.

```
<select onChange={this.handleSelectChange}>
  <option data-tag="red">Value1</option>
  <option data-tag="blue">Value2</option>
  <option data-tag="green">Value3</option>
</select>
```

I can access the value of the current selected option with:

```
handleSelectChange(e) {
  let inputValue = e.target.value;
}
```

But i also need the *data-tag* attribute of the current selected option.
How do i go about getting that?

Comment: Normal JS access doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch it in the change handler like so:

```
handleSelectChange = (e) =>{
    const dataTag = e.target.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('data-tag');
}
```